# How do i match a date format into yyyymmdd in SQL

Tags: sql, sas, type-conversion

I'm working on SQL on SAS and i'd like to use "%let" for date time.
Format of datetime in my table is

> sale_date
>
> 28AUG2018
>
> 29AUG2018

but I'm using

> %let start_date=20180828;
>
> %let end_date=20180830;
>
> WHERE put(sale_date, yymmddn8.) between "&start_date." and "&end_date."

I've got the error "Data Type "sale_date" does not match a Defined Type name."
How do I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have use date , you need to use date literal you have to use like as shown below

```
proc sql;
 select * from sashelp.buy
 where date between "01JAN1997"D and "30JAN2007"D ;
```

Macrovariables are referenced by & not %. To make your code work you need to change it as follows

```
%let start_date="01JAN1997"D ;
%let end_date="30JAN2007"D;
proc sql;
 select * from sashelp.buy
where date between &start_date and &end_date ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more context for your error message as it does not look like the type of error you would get from that code.

Your posted `WHERE` statement should work since you are converting `SALE_DATE` into a character string in the form yyyymmdd and comparing it to other character strings.  Note that if your variable `SALE_DATE` display values in ddMONyyyy then it is probably has DATE values (number of days) and not DATETIME values (number of seconds).  The only way to display a DATETIME value in that way is if your variable has the `DTDATE9.` format attached to it.  The other possibility is that `SALE_DATE` is actually a character variable and not a numeric value of any type.

If `SALE_DATE` is really a datetime value then you will need to use the `DATEPART()` function to convert it to a date value to apply the YYMMDDN8. format to it.

```
WHERE put(datepart(sale_date), yymmddn8.) between "&start_date." and "&end_date."
```

To enter a date literal you need a quoted string followed by the letter `d`.  The values need to be in a format that the `DATE` informat can read. So something like `"28AUG2018"d`.  Then you could just compare those to the variable and not have to convert it first.

```
%let start_date=28AUG2018;
%let end_date=30AUG2018;
WHERE sale_date between "&start_date."d and "&end_date."d
```

Or if the variable is really DATETIME then use datetime literals instead.

```
WHERE sale_date between "&start_date:00:00"dt and "&end_date:23:59"dt
```